# Can TFS do "favorites" or user-defined groupings of team projects?

Tags: tfs

Is it possible for users to create their own list of team projects across collections?

An example of the proposed TFS structure:

```
Collection1\TeamProject1
Collection1\TeamProject2

Collection2\TeamProject3
Collection2\TeamProject4
```

If user1 wanted to view only TeamProject1 and TeamProject4, they would be able to create their own index of teamprojects that include just those two.

I know this is possible within a collection, as they just select the project(s) within the collection they wish to open.  Is there a way to do this across collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. A single connection to one Team Collection is possible at a time, and then any number of Team Projects within this Collection can be selected to be viewed.
I simply open two Visual Studio instances and open in each a connection to another Collection.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will be implemented in TFS11, according to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/09/19/the-new-team-explorer-in-tfs-11.aspx) the process will be streamlined a bit, so I'd hope people will be able to work across multiple collections easier.

Comment: Very interesting article Daniel.  I hope when 11 comes out, my employer upgrades!